# "Translation" of Transform from FireFox to IE10

Tags: css, internet-explorer, transform

I do have the following style in FF:

```
opacity: 1; 
transform: translate3d(-95.1115px, -25.2431px, 0px) scale(0.7047); 
transform-origin: 140.107px 70.2427px 0px;opacity: 1;
```

I know that it is not working in IE10/IE11 out of the box.

I already found out, that the scale needs to be multiplied with 10

```
transform: scale(7.047);
```

to have the same effect.

But the other transforms, I have no clue how to convert them to IE10/11.

Any Ideas?

Comment: This might be of use to you: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj127312(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Thanks, tried it, but i really don't find the relation between the already given parameters in FF and the transform, which need to be in IE.